# Disable 'snap scrolling' in listview/gridview WinRT

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, windows-runtime

I may not know what to really call it. But in my app when I scroll a long listview or gridview using touch, the control tries to stop the scrolling in between two elements of the list. So that the top element does not appear half cut.
This is although a feature but I think lot of calculations must be going on backstage to increase or decrease inertia and so it kind of hampers the fluidity of the scroll action.

Is there any property of the scrollviwer that can disable it?

Comment: ADD: My app is a universal 8.1 XAML app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after wasting a lot of time fiddling with properties of scrollviewer

Following properties of scrollviewer modify the snapping behaviour. By default it is set to 'mandatory'

```
HorizontalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalSnapPointsType="None"
```